# Java replace method, replacing with empty character

Tags: java, string

Suppose I have the following in `String` format:

`2.2`

And I want to replace the decimal point with an empty space, to make it look like this:

`22`

How do I do this? I thought `replace` would have done the trick, but when I try it like this:

`string.replace('.', '');`

I get an error with the `''` because it supposedly isn't a character. That makes sense, so how else can I accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you just exchange single for double quotes, this will work because an empty string is a legal value, as opposed to an "empty character", and there's an overload `replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)`. Keep in mind that `CharSequence` is the supertype of `String`.

Comment: I get an error saying that `The method replace(char, char) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (char, String)`

Comment: @capcom You want `string.replace(".", "")`

Comment: Oh I tried that, but I get an error during run time. I should have mentioned that this is for Android. So my app is force closed if I use double quotes in `replace`.

Comment: Strings are immutable, so `replace()` won't change the string, it will return a new one. You will have to write `yourString = yourString.replace(".", "");`

Comment: @jlordo Ya, I have that too. That's not the problem, so I left that out for simplicity.

Answer (score 31):

try :

```
string.replace(".", "");
```

Other way is to use `replaceAll` :

```
string.replaceAll("\\.","");
```

Comment: A downside of using replaceAll is the it will be processed as regex, so always prefer replace over replaceAll when possible.