# Java string.split a split string

Tags: java, string

My data is Like this:

```
Smith, Bob; Data; More Data
Doe, John; Data; More Data
```

If you look below you'll see that I'm trying to split the FullName into first and last. 
The error is:

"The method split(String) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (char)"

```
String line = scanner.nextLine();
String[] data = line.split(";");
String[] fullName = data[0].split(',');
```

Comment: The error is self-explanatory: `','` → `","`.

Comment: Oh god. Thank you. if you post that as an answer I'll set it.

Comment: Sure, see my answer below.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13209877/1281433)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I explained in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041698/java-string-split-a-split-string/19041740#comment28139899_19041698) that the error could be fixed quite easily: `','` → `","`.

I'll just give some details as to why this is the case. In Java, single characters enclosed in `'`s are [*character literals*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.4), which are very different from [*string literals*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5), enclosed in `"`s. If you're coming from the world of Python, for example, this might take some time to get used to since there `'` and `"` can be used essentially synonymously.

In any case, the 1-argument [`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method of `String` accepts *only* a `String` which is in turn parsed as a regular expression. That's why you need the double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Switch the single quotes to double

`String[] fullName = data[0].split(",")`;

Comment: u mean single quotes to double rite?

Answer (score 0):

[**String.split(String)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a String as the lone parameter.

```
public String[] split(String regex)

    Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.

    This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the
    given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are
    therefore not included in the resulting array.

    The string "boo:and:foo", for example, yields the following results with
    these expressions:

        Regex   Result
        :   { "boo", "and", "foo" }
        o   { "b", "", ":and:f" }

    Parameters:
        regex - the delimiting regular expression 
    Returns:
        the array of strings computed by splitting this string around matches
        of the given regular expression 
    Throws:
        PatternSyntaxException - if the regular expression's syntax is invalid
    Since:
        1.4
    See Also:
        Pattern
```